# Using a variable array to create jQuery blur events

Tags: javascript, validation, multidimensional-array, jquery

I have a multidimensional array of form field ids and which type of error checking they have on them.  I want to add a blur event to each of the error fields so when the user leaves it to go to the next field it will make sure the field is valid.

I created a for loop with the blur event creation and an alert to make sure the blur is being created for that field.  The alert tells all the fields have the validation added, but when I go to test it on the page, no matter what field I'm leaving the blur event validates the last field in the array only.

Here is the function.

```
function SetErrorFields(fields) {
    var ErrorFields = fields;

    for (Field in ErrorFields) {
        alert("Field: "+ErrorFields[Field][0]+" | Validations: "+ErrorFields[Field][1]);
        $('#'+ErrorFields[Field][0]).blur(function(){
            Validate(ErrorFields[Field][0],ErrorFields[Field][1]);
        });
    }

}
```

I've tried changing a couple of things, but either nothing has worked or things get worse.  Bellow is a list of what I tried and the result.

Changed ErrorFields[Field][0] to Field[0], but that changes everything in the alert to "undefined".

Using the following code throws "x is undefined" errors, when leaving the field.

```
for (x=0; x<ErrorFields.length; x++) {
    alert("Field: "+ErrorFields[x][0]+" | Validations: "+ErrorFields[x][1]);
    $('#'+ErrorFields[x][0]).blur(function(){
        Validate(ErrorFields[x][0],ErrorFields[x][1]);
    });
}
```

And I can't figure out the each method.

Comment: It never ceases to amuse me that after I post a problem, I discover a solution.  Will be posting shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a useful parameter called eventData.  It lets you send data to an event when it's declared.  The below works.

```
function SetErrorFields(fields) {
    ErrorFields = fields;
    for (Field in ErrorFields) {
        alert(ErrorFields[Field][0]+" | "+ErrorFields[Field][1]+" | "+$('#'+ErrorFields[Field][0]).val());
        $('#'+ErrorFields[Field][0]).blur({fld: ErrorFields[Field][0], err: ErrorFields[Field][1]}, function(event){
            Validate(event.data.fld,event.data.err);
        });
    }

}
```

For a more indepth explanation on what it does go [here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#passing-event-data).